# Select folder (Inbox) and execute macro in email moved

Tags: vba, outlook

I've got a macro that moves each e-mail in a `subfolder` to inbox, and works perfectly!
But how can I call a macro to that specific e-mail that has been moved?

Macro to move email:

```
Public Sub Mover_Email()
'   // Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items

    On Error GoTo MsgErr
'    Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("1 - Arquivos Temporarios")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

'   // Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Items.count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items(lngCount)

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
'           // Set SubFolder of Inbox
            Set SubFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'           // Mark As Read
            Item.UnRead = False
'           // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
            Item.Move SubFolder
            'Call the macro for that email
            '************
            'Enter the macro here
            '************
        End If
    Next lngCount

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

    Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```

I thought that selecting the folder "Inbox" and execute the macro in that e-mail could work, but I don't know how.

If there's some other simple solution, I'd prefer that (like not selecting the Inbox maybe).

Comment: Are you trying to move the email from sub-folder back to inbox?

Comment: Yes @0m3r, I'm! Because I've got some e-mails with the same subject, so when I execute a macro, he finds two emails and execute both of them simultaneously, instead of separetely. So my solution was moving them to another folder and then moving them back one by one and executing the main macro.

Comment: So when you run the code your would like to only move 1 email? the selected email?

Comment: see second code on my answer.

Comment: @0m3r I aswered on tha post then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the mail is lost in the move.

Create a reference to the moved mail with `Set movedItem = …`.

```
Public Sub Move_first_then_Process_Email()

'   // Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Folder
    Dim SubFolder As Folder
'    Dim olNs As NameSpace
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim Items As Items

    Dim movedItem As MailItem

'   Not when developing
'    On Error GoTo MsgErr

'    Set Inbox Reference
'   Not needed when using Session
'    Set olNs = GetNamespace("MAPI")

     Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("1 - Arquivos Temporarios")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

'   // Set target folder
    Set SubFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'   // Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set Item = Items(lngCount)

        Debug.Print "Subject of Item: " & Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
'
'           // Mark As Read
            Item.UnRead = False

'           // Move Mail Item to target folder
'               and create a reference to the moved item
            Set movedItem = Item.Move(SubFolder)

            'Call the macro for moved email
            '************
            display_Subject movedItem
            '************

        End If

    Next lngCount

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

    Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub

Private Sub display_Subject(ByRef mvItem As Object)
    If mvItem.Class = olMail Then
        Debug.Print "Subject of movedItem: " & mvItem.Subject
        Debug.Print
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not a mailitem."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I do that @nilton? Where should I write this `Set movedItem = …`? Also, where should I call my macro for that email that has been moved?

Comment: It worked! I read your code again, and understand what you did! I called my macro as `Call Example(Item)`, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

*Work with [**NameSpace.PickFolder method (Outlook)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.pickfolder)*

*Example*

```
Set Inbox = Application.Session.PickFolder
```

You could also set your `Subfolder` to `PickFolder` but move it outside the loop

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Mover_Email()
'   // Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items

    On Error GoTo MsgErr
'    Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = Application.Session.PickFolder

    Set Items = Inbox.Items

'   // Set SubFolder
    Set SubFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder

'   // Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items(lngCount)

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
'           // Mark As Read
            Item.UnRead = False
'           // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
            Item.Move SubFolder
            'Call the macro for that email
            '************
            'Enter the macro here
            '************
        End If
    Next lngCount

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

    Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```

---

*To move selected Email to Inbox try the following*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Exampls()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Item As Object
    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.selection(1)

    Debug.Print Item.Parent

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        If Not Item.Parent = Inbox Then
           Item.Move Inbox
           MsgBox "Item Subject: " & Item.Subject & " Has Been Move to " & Inbox.Name
        Else
            MsgBox "Item already in " & Item.Parent
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "Selection is not MailItem"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: even if I pick a folder, the macro doesn't work for that email that has been moved, it goes to `MsgErr`.

Comment: The second code worked moving the email (my code do that as well), but how do I call on macro on that email that has been moved? I mean, after the move, how do I call the macro on that item?

Comment: It worked @0m3r! I used @nilton solution as I answered on his answer. So, after I moved the e-mail, I just called as `Call Example(Item)` after the line `Set movedItem = Item.Move(SubFolder)`, thank you very much for your time!